# Why is Chrome is no longer opening the relevant app from the universal link?

Tags: android, google-chrome, deep-linking, android-deep-link

Our team has been mantaining a web application for a couple of years now and out of the sudden last week our universal links for external apps stopped working. We currently generate links for Uber rides, Waze directions, google maps, whatsapp, facebook and facebook messenger. But as of Tuesday of last week all links are no longer opening the relevant native application on Android devices and instead users are being taken to a web view.

I've been searching in several places to see if this is either related to our code or it's the way deep links are working now, and we need to wait for the third-party apps to update. This problem is only happening with the latest version of Google Chrome (Chrome 76) for android

These are the links that used to work just a couple of weeks ago

```
<a href="https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=14.603879%2C-90.518717&navigate=yes" target="_blank"> Go with Waze </a>

<a href="https://m.uber.com/ul/?client_id=r6uyl1SUqqgmgtPx17aMk1cirWeYGu4M&action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[nickname]=Cl%C3%ADnica%2CLcda.%20Ingrid%20%20Nayen&dropoff[latitude]=14.603879&dropoff[longitude]=-90.518717" target="_blank"> Request uber ride </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Given my SO reputation I can't post this as a comment, but I just wanted to inform you about the bug report on [chromium's bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=993149):

I hope this is solved quickly, in the mean time, the [Firefox browser for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox_beta) still correctly opens deeplinks.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helps us to better communicate with our clients